# Does OpenIM support distributed tracing?

Tags: go

I have encountered several sdk-core crash, and it is VERY DIFFICULT to locate root cause. It's the same for server side.
Currently we have operationID param, but it's no use.
Is there any way to implement distributed tracing for OpenIM?